# Reference Request: Category of explicit maps between primitive recursive sets?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

[Edited]

Let $\mathsf{PR}$ be the category defined as follows:

Choose a specific presentation of Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, that is, with a specific set of terms for primitive recursive functions.

Let the objects of $\mathsf{PR}$ be any $1$-ary term $A(x)$ in PRA. (Intuitively, think of a primitive recursive set given explicitly as as as set of zeros of some term).

Let the morphisms $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ of $\mathsf{PR}$ be a $1$-ary terms $\varphi(x)$ such that $\vdash_{PRA} A(x) = 0 \Rightarrow B(\varphi((x)) = 0$. Identify two morphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi$ if PRA proves $\varphi(x) = \psi(x)$.

Composition of morphisms is composition of terms.

Question: does this category have other names or other presentations?  It seems like this category should be of interest.

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "$\vdash_{PRA}$" mean? (I read that as "proves, together with the axioms of primitive recursive arithmetic," but I just want to be sure, especially because you've already used "$PRA$" to mean something which is not a theory.

Comment: Yes, I meant it as you say.  It means proves in primitive recursive arithmetic.

Comment: What is $\Gamma$? And how do you compose these morphisms?

Comment: Is it intended that there is a morphism between any two objects (if this is a category at all, for what are the identity morphisms and what is the composition)? I can stick into $\Gamma$ something that is false, say $0 = 1$, and get a morphism from anywhere to anywhere.

Comment: Hopefully this edited versions should clear up these questions.

Comment: As it is defined now, the category seems pretty badly behaved: e.g., all nonconstant terms are mono and epi, while the only isomorphisms are those given by the $x$ term, and next to no diagrams have limits or colimits. I think it would be more natural to identify morphisms given by terms $\phi(x),\psi(x)$ whenever PRA proves $A(x)=0\to\phi(x)=\psi(x)$.

Comment: Yes, let's make that identification.

Comment: It might be more useful for you to ask the question differently. Tell us what you need a category for, and we may be able to suggest a good constructions. Categorical logicians have a few tricks in the hat, but it would be good to know what sort of rabbit you're looking for.

Comment: Intuitively, I want a category of Godel codings.  When working with discrete sets in practice one hardly ever works with some effective bijection with $\mathbb{N}$.  I'm trying to get at what remains when you abstract the details of coding away.

Restated, I'm looking for a category whose objects are primitive recursive sets (as explicit objects in PRA) together with an equivalence relation and whose morphisms are primitive recursive functions between such sets which respect these equivalence relations (together with the proofs in PRA that this is the case.)

Comment: Essentially, I want a categorical treatment of Primitive Recursive Arithmetic where $\mathbb{N}$ is not given special status.

Comment: See also http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2006-May/010490.html.